# Permissions to wp-content folder in Windows Server 2012

Tags: updates, directory, permissions, windows

I've made some tests to solve this problem: trying to update some plugins via Wordpress backend I always receive a "Unable to create folder" error.

So I've initially added `IIS_IUSRS` with Read/Write/Modify permissions (not full control), but nothing changed.

Then I've tried to add `IIS_IUSRS` with full control, but I did not solve.
My final try was to add "`Everyone`" user and give him the Read/Write/Modify permissions. And it works!

But do you think it's a security hole to give this permissions to Everyone user?
And what do you think could be a solution?

I'm using:
Windows Server 2012, Wordpress 4.0.1, PHP 5.4.24, IIS 8.0

Answer (score 3):

There are actually 3 users that IIS access files with on .NET sites: `IIS_IUSRS`, `IUSR`, and `NETWORK SERVICE`

Grant all 3 IIS users `Read & Execute`, `List Folder Contents`, `Read permissions` on the entire WP folder

For file management (e.g. plugin/theme installation & updates), grant all 3 of the IIS users Full Control on the `wp_content` folder.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but in my case your solution do not grant the possibility to do Wordpress core update.

Comment: I granted all 3 of the IIS users ***Modify*** on the `wp_content` folder explicitly and the Read, Execute, and List to the root level folder +1 for pointing me in the correct direction at least to get a new server site configured; updating the documents this time though

Answer (score 2):

I'm not positive if you need to grant `Everyone` `Full control` access to the WordPress root folder. Likewise, you don't need to grant `IIS_IUSRS`, `IUSR` and `NETWORK SERVICE` all permission to the entire Wordpress root folder either.

I was able to accomplish an upgrade recently where I only gave `IUSR` the `Modify`, `Read & Execute`, `List folder contents` and `Read` permissions to the root folder. I then revoked them after the update.

Environment:

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- WordPress 4.6.1
- PHP 5.5.38

Sources:

- [WordPress 3.9 upgrade fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253815/wordpress-3-9-upgrade-fails)
- [[Resolved] 500 Internal Server Error on wp-admin Dashboard](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/500-internal-server-error-on-wp-admin-dashboard/#post-540907)

Answer (score 0):

I found the the solution was to modify the location and permissions of the WordPress uploads folder. The problem is explained and the solution has screen shorts https://www.urtech.ca/2018/04/solved-500-error-on-downloads-in-wordpress-running-on-iis/

I hope this helps.